# Conditional order by and minimizing cost of execution

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a cursor that is very effective, but one in a million times when i open it, I want it to also order the rows in a manner that makes it slow.

The obvious solution is to have a second copy of the cursor, one with order by and the other without it.

However it's tedious, and prone to errors in future.

The question is: is it even possible to force oracle to skip the entire order by clause using a cursor parameter (without dynamic sql of course)?

Example code of what i would want to achieve:

```
declare

 cursor c_cur(skip_order varchar2) is
 select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ xes.x
  from ( select 1 x from dual union all
         select 3 x from dual union all
         select 2 x from dual
  ) xes
 order by case when skip_order = 'Y' then null else xes.x end
 ;
 type t_x is table of c_cur%rowtype;
 tab_xes t_x;
begin
   open c_cur('Y'); -- and sometimes 'N' ...
   fetch c_cur bulk collect into tab_xes;
   close c_cur;
   for info_line in (SELECT *  FROM   TABLE(DBMS_XPLAN.DISPLAY_CURSOR(null,null,'ALL')))
   loop
      dbms_output.put_line(info_line.plan_table_output);
   end loop;
end;
```

Memory used with 'Y' as parameter is lower than with 'N', but still the sort order by is there...

Edit:
forgot to add:
version used is 11.2.0.4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The question is: is it even possible to force oracle to skip the
>   entire order by clause using a cursor parameter (without dynamic sql
>   of course)?

Yes, I see 2 more solutions, but dynamic sql looks more promising.

Other possibilities:

1. Write 2 cursors (with and without order by) and choose which one to use.
2. Use `with` clause (oracle should optimize this query during execution - so looking only into execution plan is misleading):

```
    with no_order as (
    select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ xes.x
      from ( select 1 x from dual union all
             select 3 x from dual union all
             select 2 x from dual
      ) xes
      where skip_order = 'Y'
     ),
     ordered as
     (
       select /*+ gather_plan_statistics */ xes.x
        from ( select 1 x from dual union all
               select 3 x from dual union all
               select 2 x from dual
        ) xes
        where skip_order != 'Y'
        order by xes.x
     )
      select *
      from no_order
      union all
      select *
      from ordered
     ;
```

Comment: Thanks, option #2 was pretty much what i needed (and used before, don't know why i forgot about it)